# What are possible consequences for the screen, when doing the replacement of iPhone 5s home button

Tags: screen, iphone, repair

I need to replace the fingerprint sensor along with the home button on my iPhone 5s, but I am afraid of what would the consequences be on the screen. Right now, the screen assembly seems to be perfectly flush and tight with the frame. In particular, I know that there are often problems with closing it after the repair. Will I be able to close it just fine and will it be perfectly flush as it is right now? Any experiences guys? Any iPhone 5s repair masters? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you apply common sense when replacing Touch ID/the home button you should be fine:

- all screws go back to the **same thread** they came from
- **tighten the screws** so they won't stick out
- make sure to properly align the screen to the top of the case first
- pay attention to the flex cables - put them in all the way into the ZIF connector

I recommend to watch a few 5s display repair videos if you never have replaced a screen before. This should give you a better idea what diffuculties may arise.

Comment: I have replaced the iPhone screens many times on iPhone 4 and iPhone 5, one time I think I cracked something on a 5 and it never fitted snugly any more. Thatàs my concern, what to take care of when opening-closing the lid.